# async/await slower than callback

Tags: javascript, callback, async-await

I'm trying to convert callbacks to async/await, but found that async/await is much slower than the existing callbacks. Can anyone see what's wrong with my async/await?

```
for (var i = 0; i < balance; i++) {      
  tokenOfOwnerByIndex().call(i).then((id) => {           
      tokenURI().call(id).then((uri) => {
          console.log(uri);
      });
  });         
}
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < balance; i++) {
  var id = await this.getTokenOfOwnerByIndex(i);
  var uri = await this.getTokenURI(id);
  console.log(uri);
}
```

Comment: What is the callback code that you're comparing with?

Comment: I don't see any timing mechanism in the code, how to you verify one is slower than the other?

Comment: Your first version calls `tokenOfOwnerByIndex()` a bunch of times in parallel. Your second version does everything in series.

Comment: You could fix it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m3c4bn7e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` is called returning a promise. You attach a callback via `then`, and the loop continues. The promise will eventually resolve, but your for loop is done long before that.

When you use await, you are blocking following code, until the promise resolves. This means that each call to `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` has to resolve, before the for loop continues.

See my code for an example.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

console.time('promise');
let c = 10;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  sleep(100)
    .then(() => {
      c--;
      if (c === 0) {
        console.timeEnd('promise');
      }
    });
}


console.time('await');
(async () => {
  let c = 10;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await sleep(100);
    c--;
    if (c === 0) {
      console.timeEnd('await');
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: ok makes sense. so in this case i should stick with the callback then?

Comment: If your asynchronous functions aren't codependent, then yes -- run them in parallel, perfect use case for asynchronous code. You could also but all the returned promises in an array and use one the current Promise combinators like `Promise.all` if you need all promises to resolve or `Promise.race` if you need to bail if any of them rejects.

Comment: or the code I posted in a JSFiddle which just merpyderps the awaits into an async immediately invoked arrow function.

Comment: what does `_` mean that comes right after async in your JSFiddle?

Comment: `_` is a valid Javascript identifier and is actually the parameter of the async arrow function. You can write `async () => ...` instead, if you don't want it

Comment: Thanks. so performance wise, is Paulpro's async faster than callbacks?

Comment: You have to write some perfs yourself, but I think the *most* performant way would be to the `tokenOfOwnerByIndex(i).then(....)` approach in each loop iteration. I think the performance differences are nigh negligible though

Comment: Both cases are not equivalent. Callback case is running all promises at the same time. Await case is waiting for every promise to start the next one. That's why the await case is a lot slower. You can just ignore the `await` keyword in `await sleep(100);` line to have the same result